# JFrame doesn't re-maximize after Minimization

Tags: java, swing, jframe, minimize, maximize

I'm having trouble getting a custom JFrame to maximize itself correctly after being minimized. Here's the process I've gone through: I open the frame, maximize it (code below), minimize it, and re-open the program from the dock. However, when I re-open the frame it is back to its original size, not the maximized size it was in before I minimized it.

These methods get called when the maximize and minimize buttons are pushed. This is a custom JFrame, and it is undecorated, so I made buttons for these actions.

```
private void maximizeAction(){
    setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}//=================================

private void minimizeAction(){
    setExtendedState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
}//=================================
```

I tried adding a `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));` line to the maximize function, but that didn't change the behavior of the frame when I re-opened it.

Other possible contributing factors might be:

- The frame has transparency and a unique frame shape, so I have overridden the `paint()` command. However, I use inherited variables, so those should be accurate. It's like the frame has forgotten how big it was.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the previous extended state.

```
private void minimizeAction(){
    setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | Frame.ICONIFIED);
}//=================================
```

Comment: That code throws an error for me. I maximize the frame, then click the minimize button (after implementing your code) and I get the following error:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown window state: 7`